# What is the name of this "" notation and what does it mean?

Tags: notation

I've come across an expression from the [Stanford Neural Network Course Note](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/) that looks like this:

[image]

(where `a`, `b`, `c` are parameter vectors)

What is the name of this notation "" and what does it mean / do? i.e.

[image]

I guess it means "1" (one) but not entirely sure as it seems to be written in a specific way for a reason? (could it be that it means `true` if `x` is within the range `a` to `b`, and `false` if `x` is outside that range? Boolean related?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). In your case,

$$
\mathbf 1(a_i < x < b_i)(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } a_i < x < b_i \\ 0 & \text{ else} \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2):

It is the "indicator function". It equals one when the conditions in the subscript are met, and zero otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

From the (little) context, my guess is that $$1\!\!1(\phi(x))=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }\phi(x)\\0&\text{if }\neg\phi(x)\end{cases}$$